# Pandas/Google BigQuery: Schema mismatch makes the upload fail

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

The schema in my google table looks like this:

```
price_datetime : DATETIME,
symbol         : STRING,
bid_open       : FLOAT,
bid_high       : FLOAT,
bid_low        : FLOAT,
bid_close      : FLOAT,
ask_open       : FLOAT,
ask_high       : FLOAT,
ask_low        : FLOAT,
ask_close      : FLOAT
```

After I do a `pandas.read_gbq` I get a `dataframe` with column dtypes like this:

```
price_datetime     object
symbol             object
bid_open          float64
bid_high          float64
bid_low           float64
bid_close         float64
ask_open          float64
ask_high          float64
ask_low           float64
ask_close         float64
dtype: object
```

Now I want to use `to_gbq` so I convert my local dataframe (which I just made) from these dtypes:

```
price_datetime    datetime64[ns]
symbol                    object
bid_open                 float64
bid_high                 float64
bid_low                  float64
bid_close                float64
ask_open                 float64
ask_high                 float64
ask_low                  float64
ask_close                float64
dtype: object
```

to these dtypes:

```
price_datetime     object
symbol             object
bid_open          float64
bid_high          float64
bid_low           float64
bid_close         float64
ask_open          float64
ask_high          float64
ask_low           float64
ask_close         float64
dtype: object
```

by doing:

```
df['price_datetime'] = df['price_datetime'].astype(object)
```

Now I (think) I am read to use `to_gbq` so I do:

```
import pandas
pandas.io.gbq.to_gbq(df, <table_name>, <project_name>, if_exists='append')
```

but I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidSchema                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d5a3f86ad382> in <module>()
      1 a = time.time()
----> 2 pandas.io.gbq.to_gbq(df, <table_name>, <project_name>, if_exists='append')
      3 b = time.time()
      4 
      5 print(b-a)

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, verbose, reauth, if_exists, private_key)
    825         elif if_exists == 'append':
    826             if not connector.verify_schema(dataset_id, table_id, table_schema):
--> 827                 raise InvalidSchema("Please verify that the structure and "
    828                                     "data types in the DataFrame match the "
    829                                     "schema of the destination table.")

InvalidSchema: Please verify that the structure and data types in the DataFrame match the schema of the destination table.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to do two things that solved the issue for me. First, I deleted my table and reuploaded it with the columns as `TIMESTAMP` types rather than `DATETIME` types. This made sure that the schema matched when the `pandas.DataFrame` with column type `datetime64[ns]` was uploaded to using `to_gbq`, which converts `datetime64[ns]` to `TIMESTAMP` type and not to `DATETIME` type ([for now](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/issues/69)).

The second thing I did was upgrade from `pandas 0.19` to `pandas 0.20`. These two things solved my problem of a schema mismatch.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably an issue related to pandas. If you check the code for [to_gbq](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L947), you'll see that it runs this code:

```
table_schema = _generate_bq_schema(dataframe)
```

Where `_generate_bq_schema` is given by:

```
def _generate_bq_schema(df, default_type='STRING'):
    """ Given a passed df, generate the associated Google BigQuery schema.
    Parameters
    ----------
    df : DataFrame
    default_type : string
        The default big query type in case the type of the column
        does not exist in the schema.
    """

    type_mapping = {
        'i': 'INTEGER',
        'b': 'BOOLEAN',
        'f': 'FLOAT',
        'O': 'STRING',
        'S': 'STRING',
        'U': 'STRING',
        'M': 'TIMESTAMP'
    }

    fields = []
    for column_name, dtype in df.dtypes.iteritems():
        fields.append({'name': column_name,
                       'type': type_mapping.get(dtype.kind, default_type)})

    return {'fields': fields}
```

As you can see, there's no type mapping to `DATETIME`. This inevitably gets mapped to type `STRING` (since its `dtype.kind` is "O") and then conflict occurs.

The only work around for now that I'm aware of would be to change your table schema from `DATETIME` to either `TIMESTAMP` or `STRING`.

It probably would be a good idea to start a new issue on pandas-bq repository asking to update this code to accept `DATETIME` as well.

[EDIT]:

I've opened this [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/issues/69) in their repository.

Comment: I checked what the `_generate_bq_schema` would convert `datetime64[ns]`  to and it seems to convert it to `M` which would return a `TIMESTAMP` object. So I am not sure this is the issue.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, the issue that you opened is appropriate in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Extract in the BigQuery Schema, generate the schema pandas_gbq would generate if you try loading your data into BigQuery and take a look at the differences.

```
import logging

from google.cloud import bigquery
from pandas_gbq import schema

# Load BQ schema
client =  bigquery.Client()
table = client.get_table(f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}")

# Put it in Pandas
f_tuples = [(field.name, field.field_type) for field in table.schema]
bq_schema = pd.DataFrame.from_records(f_tuples, columns = ["name", "type"])
bq_schema = bq_schema.set_index("name")

# Generate the load schema
load_schema = pd.json_normalize(schema.generate_bq_schema(df)["fields"])
load_schema = load_schema.set_index("name")

# Use the following code to check whether the field is a field in BQ 
# and whether it's the same field type
for i in load_schema.index:
    try:
        b_type = bq_schema.loc[i, "type"]
        l_type = load_schema.loc[i, "type"]
    except KeyError:
        logging.warning(f'{i} not in BigQuery Schema')
    try:
        assert b_type == l_type
    except AssertionError:
        logging.warning(f'{i} with {l_type} does not match {b_type}')
```

This snippet will give the following log if the field is not in the BQ schema

```
2022-11-25 12:38:16,249 WARNING TEST not in BigQuery Schema (950218398.<cell line: 31>:36)
```

This snippet will give the following log if the field types do not match

```
2022-11-25 12:36:29,304 WARNING domain_userid with TEST does not match STRING (2236687881.<cell line: 30>:39)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and determined that Pandas is sending the columns in alphabetical order by column_name, which, in my case, mismatched the schema of the BigQuery Table. Hence, a column was expecting a date value when it got an integer, etc. It thus, throws the "Invalid Schema" error. Check your column order.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the pandas-gbq documentation, you can supply the schema yourself - "If the data type inference does not suit your needs, supply a BigQuery schema as the table_schema parameter of to_gbq()."

https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing.html