# to_gbq timestamp - InvalidSchema

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create and append pandas data to a bigquery table. My data has the following format

id : asdg-123-asda-23as (STRING)
timestamp : 2018-01-01T01:24:29.020Z (TIMESTAMP)
measure1 : 123.456 (FLOAT)
measute3 etc...

and the command I'm running is data_frame.to_gbq(...). I get the error

InvalidSchema: Please verify that the structure and data types in the DataFrame match the schema of the destination table.

From previous post I can see that the timestamp is matched to a string hence the mismatch.

How should I format the timestamp column? What is bigquery expecting?

I've tried a few things (e.g. pd.to_datetime) but no luck thus far

Comment: Take a look at the solution to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953463/pandas-google-bigquery-schema-mismatch-makes-the-upload-fail/44960645#44960645 - running the sample code here helped me resolve a similar issue by adding the `def _generate_bq_schema` directly to my code and checking the results against the table I'd created.

Comment: Also, note that as per the Pandas documentation you can now use define the schema yourself with the `table_schema` parameter: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html

Comment: Thanks Ben P. The odd part (bug?) is that if I create a stub table with defined schema then data_frame.to_gbq with an append fails. Yet if I don't bother with the stub, create the table with the data_frame.to_gbq and then append the same data_frame.to_gbq it's fine. The schemas are identical!

Comment: Hm yes certainly sounds odd! Perhaps an old schema is stuck in cache somewhere, glad you found a workaround anyway!

Comment: Can you verify the schemas of the two tables are identical? Because from your data format and from what you describe it seems that the error you were getting was due to your table having DATETIME for your "timestamp" field. However, if you don't create any table in advance, the data_frame.to_gbq command will create your table with TIMESTAMP for your "timestamp" field. This is indeed related to the SO case shared by @BenP (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953463/pandas-google-bigquery-schema-mismatch-makes-the-upload-fail/44960645#44960645)

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp column was the issue for me, and not exactly sure why, but deleting the table and creating it via pandas-gbq with a table schema did the trick for me. Nothing else worked, even though the schemas matched exactly what I was doing.

Example:

```
    table_schema = [
        {"name": "column_name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
        {"name": "timestamp", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    ]
    df.to_gbq(
        destination,
        project_id=gcp_id,
        if_exists="append",
        credentials=credentials,
        table_schema=table_schema,
    )
```

Note: as to your original question, I had it in datetime64[s] format, which it was fine with once table had been recreated via to_gbq, but not before that